# How to put custom layout in 404 error page instead of default layout in cake php2.x

Tags: cakephp

i have created a error400.ctp in Errors view. that take the default layout but i want to change the custom layout

below are my code i used but that won't work

```
public function error404() {
    $this->layout = 'customlayout'; // here i user customlayout instead of default
}
```

please suggest me how to use my custom layout

Thanks Sanjib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after doing lots of research finally i get the solution

Change the ExceptionRenderer in core.php to use your own renderer.

app/Config/core.php:

```
Configure::write('Exception', array(
  'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleException',
  'renderer' => 'MyExceptionRenderer',
  'log' => true
));
```

then create new file MyExceptionRenderer.php

app/Lib/Error/MyExceptionRenderer.php:

```
<?php
App::uses('ExceptionRenderer', 'Error');

class MyExceptionRenderer extends ExceptionRenderer {

  protected function _outputMessage($template) {
    $this->controller->layout = 'innerdefault';
    parent::_outputMessage($template);
  }

}
?>
```

this works fine for me, lets try and share you thought

Comment: have you done it well but i have tried and it works for me. i have tried in many project. please go though again it will work